# How to deploy Unity Asset Server on OpenShift?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, openshift

I just found that OpenShift started to support .Net apps, and I want do dev my unity3d indie--game using that service.

At first I need to setting up Asset Server, as I am more frontend developer and newbie at backemd developing, I have a questions with deploying Unity Asset Server on OpenShift.
Just is possible at all?
What I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.net is part of openshift origin (community project) but is not available on openshift online.  You can not run .net applications on openshift online natively, only with the community supported mono cartridge: https://github.com/wshearn/openshift-community-cartridge-mono